# Sort array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I have such code:

```
Manufacturer.all.collect {|p| [ p.MFA_BRAND, p.MFA_ID ] }
```

I'm new, i know only how to sort AR objects, but how to do in my case, becouse i need also collect....
So how to sort my array and collect?

Comment: what are you sorting by, brand or id?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev  all is ok what i have.... just for this i need to sort via MFA_BRAND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort AR records using `order`, then collect what you want:

```
Manufacturer.order(:MFA_BRAND).all.collect{|p| [p.MFA_BRAND, p.MFA_ID]}
```

Alternatively, you can sort as a ruby Enumerable before or after collecting:

```
Manufacturer.all.sort_by(&:MFA_BRAND).collect{|p| [p.MFA_BRAND, p.MFA_ID] }
Manufacturer.all.collect{|p| [p.MFA_BRAND, p.MFA_ID] }.sort_by{|r| r[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the sort and sort_by functions in the Enumerable module.  Array is an Enumerable. Search for examples on the web.

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris: please keep the comments polite and to the point.  He is merely pointing out that this answer is probably not difficult to find if you do a bit of legwork.

Comment: @PinnyM with you, man, all is ok... i tried just .sort_by{|r| r.MFA_BRAND}  and get errors